# Why won't KWin config BorderlessMaximizedWindows persist?

Tags: persistence, kwin

I just changed `BorderlessMaximizedWindows` setting in `~/.config/kwinrc` to `true` to hide window title bar and it works, but after restart of my PC my kwin config is reset to default settings, so `BorderlessMaximizedWindows` is set to `false` again.

How to make these settings persistent after restart?

Output from `inxi -Sxxx`:

```
System:    Host: tomsk-U36SD Kernel: 4.15.0-33-generic x86_64 (64 bit gcc: 5.4.0)
           Desktop: KDE Plasma 5.13.5 (Qt 5.11.1) dm: sddm,sddm Distro: neon 16.04 xenial
```

**UPDATE:**

The problem was with Latte Dock:
[Can I have different BorderlessMaximized windows option between different layouts?](https://github.com/psifidotos/Latte-Dock/wiki/Tips-&-Tricks#q-can-i-have-different-borderlessmaximized-windows-option-between-different-layouts)

Comment: @DKBose Thank you and config file is saved in `~/.config/latte/{profile_name}` and the key is called `disableBordersForMaximizedWindows`.

Answer (score 3):

<sub>(This answer is based on info found in the question and comments...  writing this in case link stops working someday...)</sub>

My KWin setting for BorderlessMaximizedWindows started resetting after I installed Latte Dock on a few computers.  Only one computer was affected.  It is related to a feature that allows different dock layouts to have different border settings for maximized windows.  (See [Can I have different BorderlessMaximized windows option between different layouts?](https://userbase.kde.org/LatteDock/FAQ#Can_I_have_different_Borderless_Maximized_windows_options_between_different_layouts.3F))

The following commands will return KWin to its previous behavior:

```
kwriteconfig5 --file ~/.config/lattedockrc --group UniversalSettings --key canDisableBorders false
latte-dock -r &

kwriteconfig5 --file ~/.config/kwinrc --group Windows --key BorderlessMaximizedWindows true
qdbus org.kde.KWin /KWin reconfigure
```

They correspond with unchecking "Support borderless maximized windows in different layouts" in the Preferences tab of the Latte Dock settings dialog.

[image: latte dock settings 1]

---

Alternatively, you can enable the setting and check the "Borderless" option (by double clicking) for the desired layouts in the Layout tab.

[image: latte dock settings 2]